# Pattern for creating and accessing temporary data for multiple http request?

Tags: design-patterns

I want to store temporary data that can be accessed across multiple http request.
The question may be similar to [How to persist temporary data over multiple HTTP requests?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/198630/how-to-persist-temporary-data-over-multiple-http-requests). The accepted answer is too specific to ASP. However, in my case i'm using rails as the framework. I want to know possible pattern that at least will solve the problem on my environment and use case.

Environtment:
Server side:

- Rails 4
- Redis
- postgresql
- Sidekiq

Client Side:

- Chrome / Firefox

Use case:
Client make a request to create an object on server side, and make the object accessible at least one day in multiple http connection. The data to store is a hash with value of strings, a long strings, that can take up to thousands of characters.

I tried few different approach to accomplish this, for example :

- List item Using temporary database object.

  I created a column to mark the data as temporary. And i created a worker to delete the temporary data everyday.

  The problem with this approach is create alot of temporary data and make the database dirty.
- Using cookie as the storage

  Cookie is great choice but is it can hold up string with thousands of chars ?

Is there any better approach for me to store temporary data ? The pattern that works in rails will be acceptable, but it will be better if it is general and can be applied to different framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is as some kind of (HTTP) Session.
You can uses a cookie to store the reference id within your session store.

You already using *Redis* and 
*Redis* is a "perfect" persistence to store session data. All operations are performed in memory, and so reads and writes will be fast.

*Redis* provides a way to set the time to live or the entries so there is no need for a cleanup job.

There is  a *GitHub* project called https://github.com/roidrage/redis-session-store